# Function to grab specific image IDs from media library.

Tags: images, get-posts, media-library, id

I want to grab images 161 thru 166 without having to calling my entire media library array and having to splice those up. In time, the more I have in there the more it's going to slow my site down. Here is what I have so far, I use array_reverse to reverse the IDs so the most recent uploads are last and I use array_splice to find the images I need to extract. Is there a more direct way for me to find images with ID 161 thru 166?

```
function get_images_from_media_library() {
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'attachment',
                    'post_mime_type' =>'image',
                    'post_status' => 'inherit',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                );
                $query_images = new WP_Query( $args );
                $images = array();
                foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image) {
                    $images[]= $image->guid;
                }
                $images = array_reverse($images);
                $images = array_splice($images, 3,6);
                return $images;
            }

            $img = get_images_from_media_library();
            foreach($img as $image){
                echo "<img src='$image'/>";
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `post__in` (two underscores) to your `$args`:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' =>'image',
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post__in' => array( 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166 ),
);
```

#### Reference

[WP_Query on the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters)

Comment: Ahh, I was looking at the wrong WP reference pages. Thanks, I've bookmarked  WP_Query, now will be referring to that more.

Comment: I generally have about three or ten tabs open to Codex pages when I'm developing WP stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If you have all the IDs of images you want then you just need to use the [wp_get_attachment_image](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image)() function in your loop.

Create an array of all the required ids and iterate through the array applying the above function which will show all the images.

Ex.

`wp_get_attachment_image($post->ID, /*size of image*/);`